# Getting a floating UL to properly cover a floating DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm hoping someone more experienced in CSS can point me in the right direction. I have a menu created with UL HTML and styled with CSS and JQuery and everything works great. Now when I go to put content below the menu, when the menu gets dropped down the content below it is messed up.

I've created an example of what's happening here:
http://jsfiddle.net/utdream/FchkJ/3/

My menu is working exactly how I want it to, but I need to make it so that the content below it does not change when the menu is opened. Is that possible?

I would prefer to not use `position: absolute;` because I want the manu and the content below it to scroll naturally with the page. I'm just not sure it's possible.

Thanks in advance for any direction anyone can offer!

Comment: Didn't look at the code, but why  not [use menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/) versus reinventing it?

Comment: @RyanB Because I wanted the learning experience of doing it myself and customizing it to exactly how I want it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not change the position of the content dropdown menu should have a `position: absolute` must therefore  to add `.MainMenu {position: absolute}`
and you have to fix the width of the drop-down menu

Comment: Apparently I was misunderstanding the use of position: absolute. In a previous test I did with it it fixed the position of the menu on the entire page and the menu moved with the scrolling. This post helped me re-evaluate position: absolute and it is indeed what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
#nav{position:absolute; z-index:999;}
```